# How to split partition on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I have partition where Microsoft's Windows is installed: 84.4 Gb free of 104Gb. How can I split this partition to get a new partition on arch Linux without erase Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Use a modern partition editor, such as gparted.

Live boot using an Gnu/Linux that has gparted. ( There is a partition editing live distro that you can use).

- Start gparted
- Resize the Windows partition
- Add a new partition in the gap left behind.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Windows built-in Disk Management (right click on Computer - > Manage). There is partition resizing option.

Comment: Can it resize a partition that is mounted?

Comment: Yes, shrink option is available for system partition(C:).

Comment: What about locked files?